# How to prune a decision tree properly in R

Tags: r, cart

I have a sample of 12,500 observations and 12 explanatory variables. I want to build a pruning decision tree, to do that I am using the `rpart` function and then the `prune` function. My problem is that I am not sure how to build the full tree, I am using

```
rpart(*, *, *, control = (minbucket=x, minsplit=y, cp=z))
# the * are irrelevant to my question
```

to build the full tree, but I don't know what `x`, `y` and `z` should I use. All the examples I have found are with much fewer observations compared to my case.

Comment: Is your question about how to use the R code properly, or about how to build such trees more generally? If the former, it would be off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), but could be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) if it has a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536). Please clarify your question. If it is about R code, add a reproducible example & we can migrate your Q to SO for you (*please don't cross-post, though*).

Comment: Requires statistical knowledge, on topic. Thank you for sharing your question here.

Comment: Ths isn't really about _pruning_ a tree, but how to _build_ it.

Comment: Helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318409/how-to-prune-a-tree-in-r

Answer (score 2):

To put every observation into its own leaf, use `minbucket=2, minsplit=1, cp=-1`. The negative value for `cp` is to ensure that rpart doesn't end splitting prematurely.

You probably *don't* want to put every observation into its own leaf though. It just makes the pruning task more difficult, and your tree take a lot of time to fit and memory to store. You can get by with the default values of `minbucket` and `minsplit` for the most part (but `cp=-1` is ok). If you have a big dataset (much bigger than 12500 cases) you should actually increase these values.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't hurt to set cp a good deal smaller that the default of 0.01 because plotcp() will show you where you need to set cp anyway. Try 0.002.

I actually don't worry about minbucket and minsplit (no idea how much this could be hurting me), so someone else will have to help you with those.